# How do I access HTML elements created by a function? The elements are "undefined" and therefore not CSS apply-able

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all here is a fiddle of the project as a whole: http://jsfiddle.net/7tj9xjb8/

Now, I create a form containing a table with some select options and input fields. The thing I want to do is to change the visibility css property of the inputs in this form from hidden to visible once the last select option is selected ("Välj annat parti"). This is supposed to be done with a function named otherParty() that is called with an onchange attribute in the select tags. However, the variable "inputs" is undefined because the content doesn't appear to be in the actual HTML when it is called, which is strange because the function isn't called upon until the script has finished. This is probably because it's being created by another function, but my question is, how the hell do I fix this so that it works?

Here is the cut out version of the code:

```
function createDropDown() {

//These are the selects that call the otherParty function onchange. 

var select = document.createElement("select");
select.setAttribute("onchange", "otherParty()");
select.style.marginLeft = indent;
container.appendChild(form);
td.appendChild(select);

for (i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.innerHTML = type[i];
    select.appendChild(option);
}

table.appendChild(tr);
tr.appendChild(td);    

//These are the inputs that should show up

if (inputTrue) {
var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.setAttribute("name", inputType);
    input.setAttribute("alt", inputType);
    input.setAttribute("id", inputType);
    input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Annat parti");
    input.style.visibility = "hidden";
    td.appendChild(input);   
}

table.appendChild(tr);
tr.appendChild(td);

} //End of function

//Makes the inputs show up

function otherParty() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); //grab all the inputs in the form once they've been created
    inputs.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Too much code. Please post a pared-down version.

Comment: Just FYI you don't have to use `.setAttribute()` to set DOM element properties. Just set them like ordinary object properties.

Comment: @torazaburo There you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you've configured jsfiddle such that your JavaScript code is in a "load" handler, *and* you've set up your event handler in a way that makes that not work. The code should look like this:

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.onchange = otherParty;
select.style.marginLeft = indent;
container.appendChild(form);
td.appendChild(select);
```

Now once you've done that, you'll find out that this doesn't work:

```
inputs.style.visibility = "visible";
```

You simply cannot do that.  You'll have to iterate through the node list returned from `getElementsByTagName()` yourself and set the style of each one separately.

Comment: that works, I don't understand why you can't set the css property to all in one go instead of having to iterate though? Why is that?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz because the DOM APIs simply don't allow that. The object returned from `.getElementsByTagName()` is a thing called a NodeList. It provides facilities for accessing the nodes, but not for doing anything else. That sort of thing is one convenience that DOM libraries like jQuery provide.

Comment: So technically I could do it with Jquery instead? And also make it so that the inputs doesn't appear when anything in the dropdown is selected (like it is now) but only the last thing?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz well yes, you could do it with jQuery, but it won't directly help with the logic you desire for your dropdowns. (Well, it might make it a little easier to check that all the dropdowns have been set to one of the non-default selections I guess.)